# Can't get getServerSideProps in Nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, fetch, server-side-rendering

I'm new to Nextjs, but I'm trying to use getServerSideProps() to pass in props to my component but I can't seem to retrieve the data from this function.

here's my code

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async () => {
  const getActivePropertiesURL =
    'http://localhost:9090/property/getAllActiveListings';
  const res = await axios.get(getActivePropertiesURL);
  const properties = await res.data.json();
  return {
    props: {
      properties,
    }, // will be passed to the page component as props
  };
};
```

I'm just trying to console log the data from the component but it gives me undefined.

here is component code

```
export default function Gallery({ properties }: { properties: PropertyType }) {
  console.log(properties);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You don't need to parse the response to JSON, axios does this automatically. Also, is this component a page component?

Comment: is your getServerSideProps is written in a page component?

Comment: no it's not a page component. Does it have to be a page component? I guess I would have to do the server side from the page and then pass it down to the component right?

Comment: Thank you @ivanatias and Manish Jha this helped me get the function working

Answer (score 0):

For anyone new to getServerSideProps, this must be inside a page component and not a regular component in order to run this function.

Export the getServerSideProps function and then pass it into your page component as a prop and then pass the prop to the component.

Hope this helps somebody.